# Questions about SRP algorithm

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication, cryptography, srp

I trying to use SRP algorithm but I have some questions:

1. Is that a good choice to use for registration and authorization SRP algorithm with SSL/TLS? And for all other transmission using just SSL/TLS?
   I will use C# Sockets for implementation.
2. How to generate g, k, N? Is it safe to use these like app constants?
3. Is that SRP algorithm right?

   > //M-modulus, g-generator, k-multiplier, I-username, p-password, s-salt, v-pass verifier
   >
   > **Registration:**
   >
   > *Client:* s = randomString(); x = Hash(s, p); v = g^x %N;
   >
   > sendToServer(I, s, v);
   >
   > *Server:* save(I, s, v);
   >
   > **Authorization:**
   >
   > *Client:* a = random(); A = g^a %N;
   >
   > sendToServer(I, A);
   >
   > Server: if(A != 0) { b=random(); B = k*v + g^b %N;}
   >
   > sendToClient(B, s);
   >
   > u = Hash(A, B);
   >
   > if(u == 0) abortConnection();
   >
   > Client: if(B == 0) abortConnection();
   >
   > u = Hash(A, B);
   >
   > if(u == 0) abortConnection();
   >
   > x = Hash(s, p);
   >
   > S = ((B - k*(g^x %N)) ^ (a + u*x)) %N;
   >
   > K = Hash(S);
   >
   > Mc = Hash( Hash(N) XOR Hash(g), Hash(I), s, A, B, K);
   >
   > sendToServer(M);
   >
   > *Server:* S = ((A*(v^u %N)) ^ B) %N; K = Hash(S);
   >
   > Ms = Hash( Hash(N) XOR Hash(g), Hash(I), s, A, B, K);
   >
   > if(Mc == Ms) {Rs = Hash(A, M, K); sendToClient(Rs);}
   >
   > *Client:* Rc = Hash(A, M, K);
   >
   > if(Rc == Rs) ALL_OK();

Comment: You appear to have 1. backwards.  SRP usually can't be used for registration because there's not yet a shared password.

Comment: This was also posted to SO. Please dont post to multiple sites.

Comment: @RickyDemer ok, can you explain in more detail? _If you about registration step:_ "Security is provided by the complexity of the operations of the discrete logarithm - get x of v = g^x %N knowing v, g, N."([only russian source](http://habrahabr.ru/post/121021/)).

Comment: @RickyDemer Can you explain more understandable? Because I think I not quite understood your comment.